# Display objects tag before the collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

With this code I can display object's tag when the "Player" hits the object, but how could I make the tag appear before the collision? I mean, for example when the player stands 3 meters in front of the object?

```
private bool showInfo = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        showInfo = true;
    }

}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo)
{

     if (collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
         showInfo = false;
     }
  }

void OnGUI()
{

    if (showInfo)
    {
        GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();

        Font myFont = (Font)Resources.Load("Fonts/comic", typeof(Font));
        myStyle.font = myFont;

        myStyle.fontSize = 24;

        myStyle.normal.textColor = Color.red;

        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), gameObject.tag, myStyle);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a aditional collider with the trigger option enabled, and make it bigger than the collider (to the size you want to detect the pre-collision) and call the `OnTriggerEnter` function.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision col)
{

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        showInfo = true;
    }

}
```

Or.. you can check in the update of the object the distance to the player with `Vector3.distance(Vector3 obj1, Vector3 obj2)` and if it's less than 3 meters set `showInfo` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Driconmax's solution is the way I'd do it.

However, to provide another solution you could create a 3m long raycast in the direction of your movement and if it registers a hit, show that objects information. But I reckon thats a sub-par solution in most cases